# Identifying the manufacturer and specifications of W06M bridge rectifier

Tags: identification, components, bridge-rectifier

I've got a PCB containing the below-presented bridge rectifier. I searched for "W06M" however several parts with the same part number, but from different manufacturers, were displayed to me.

Is this a general part number? If so, what characteristics does it have?

On the other hand, according to the phrase "DC", I guessed that the part was produced by "DC COMPONENTS CORP" or according to the symbol on the right, it belongs to "SEP ELECTRONICS CORP". Which one is correct?

[image: photo of component]

Comment: Compare the specs in the datasheets for those several parts. They are probably pretty similar.

Comment: I need the exact part.

Comment: Why do you need the part from same manufacturer, if all manufacturers make a part with same name and specs?

Comment: It's a bridge rectifier. It just rectifies an AC supply and either works or it doesn't unless the original design is using it for something special and requires some quirk of the device to operate in your unspecified circuit. Why do you think yours is special and that you need the **exact** part? What is its function in the original device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a really common part, or rather was in the days of through-hole technology.

A 1.5A 600V bridge rectifier, versions of which were made by most every rectifier assembler in Taiwan, and probably originally GI (a faded memory). We bought a bunch from a company named Tesla in Yugoslavia one time.

[image]

You can find their current datasheet [here](https://www.dccomponents.com/upload/product/original/710646761080.pdf). They are probably willing to sell directly if you meet minimum order requirements (maybe 10,000 pieces).

**Any** similar part will do electrically. The backwards UR marking (Underwriter's component listing) may not be on all manufacturer's versions of this.